# Exercise 4.4 in Atiyah & Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, ideals

I am working on Problem 4.4 in Atiyah & Macdonald, which asks the reader to show the following:

In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[t]$, the ideal $m = (2,t)$ is maximal and the ideal $q = (4,t)$ is $m$-primary, but is not a power of $m$.

Specifically, I'm struggling with showing that $q$ is not a power of $m$. Here is a solution to that part:

$q \neq m$ because $2 \notin q$. $q \neq m^2 = (4,2t,t^2)$ because $t \notin m^2$. For $n \geq 2$, $m^n \subset m^2$ by induction. Thus, $t \notin m^n$ for any $n \geq 2$, and $q \neq m^n$ for any $n \geq 2$. Therefore, $q$ is not a power of $m$.

My question is, how can we see that $m^n \subset m^2$ for $n \geq 2$ by induction?

Thank you!

Comment: $IJ\subset I,\,$ see the linked dupe for the simple proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any ideal $a$ and any positive integer $n$ we have $$a^{n+1}\subseteq a^n$$This follows more or less directly from the definition of ideal, and the definition of powers of ideals. Indeed, the ideal $a^{n+1}$ is generated by $\{xy\mid x\in a^n, y\in a\}$. Since $a^n$ is an ideal, this generating set, and thus all of $a^{n+1}$, lies inside $a^n$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)